# Removing superfluous functions from limits

Tags: limits

Suppose you have a quotient of form,

$$ \frac{ f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + \cdots}{ q(x) + r(x) + p(x)+\cdots}$$

Consider an expression of sort,

$$ \lim_{x \to a } \frac{ f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + \cdots}{ q(x) + r(x) + p(x) + \cdots}$$

Now, suppose this gives me $ \frac{0}{0}$

So, I can apply l'hopital on it maybe one or two times and I finally get some finite value of limit 'L'

that is,

$$ \lim_{x \to a } \frac{ f(x) + g(x) + h(x) + \cdots}{ q(x) + r(x) + p(x) + \cdots} =L$$

Now, suppose 'L' is invariant on removal of some of the functions (I'll illustrate with example)  how do I choose functions which do not contribute to limit to simplfy calculations?

Example:

$$  \lim_{ x \to 0 } \frac{ \sin x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots}{x} = \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{ \sin x }{x} $$

Now, clearly we can see that adding higher power polynomials to the limit does it not change it at all when the limit is going to 0

So, clearly limits as x goes to 0 is unaffected by polynomial terms in numerator which are have a 'degree' greater than denominator ( I don't know how to prove it but it is intuitive for me)

Now, how do I generalize this idea and be able to remove functions from limits?

Edit: I'm particularly looking for techniques for removing superflous functions from the denominator even though my illustration of what I'm saying was one in the numerator

Redit:  I'm not particularly looking for a case with first derivative only, I am looking for most general thing possible

Comment: fixed it pl check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Consider the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)+\ldots+f_m(x)}{g_1(x)+\ldots+g_n(x)}
$$
and suppose that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f_i(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g_j(x)=0,\qquad\forall i=1,\ldots,m,\ j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Moreover, suppose that
\begin{align}
&\forall i=1,\ldots,m,\ \exists h_i\in\mathbb{N}:\ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_i(x)}{(x-a)^{h_i}}=p_i\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\},\\
&\forall j=1,\ldots,n,\ \exists k_j\in\mathbb{N}:\ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g_j(x)}{(x-a)^{k_j}}=q_j\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}.
\end{align}
We can informally say that $f_i$ is an infinitesimal of order $h_i$ in $a$, and $g_j$ is an infinitesimal of order $k_j$ in $a$ (with respect to $x-a$).

If in the numerator there is one term, say $f_r$, such that $h_r$ < $h_i,\ \forall i=1,\ldots,m,\ i\neq r$, and the same happens in the denominator for, say, $k_s$ then we can write
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)+\ldots+f_m(x)}{g_1(x)+\ldots+g_n(x)}=\\
&\qquad=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\dfrac{f_1(x)}{(x-a)^{h_r}}+\ldots+\dfrac{f_m(x)}{(x-a 
    )^{h_r}}}{\dfrac{g_1(x)}{(x-a)^{k_s}}+\ldots+\dfrac{g_n(x)}{(x-a)^{k_s}}}\cdot 
    \frac{(x-a)^{h_r}}{(x-a)^{k_s}}=(*).
\end{align}
We see that the in numerator of the first factor, all ratios go to $0$, except that involving $f_r$, and the same in the denominator for $g_s$, so
$$
(*)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\dfrac{f_r(x)}{(x-a)^{h_r}}}{\dfrac{g_s(x)}{(x-a)^{k_s}}}\cdot 
    \frac{(x-a)^{h_r}}{(x-a)^{k_s}}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_r(x)}{g_s(x)},
$$
and this should answer to the question on how to eliminate unneeded terms in numerator and/or in denominator. Moreover, using previous knowledge, we can also say that
$$
(*) = \frac{p_r}{q_s}\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)^{h_r-s_s},
$$
that is a limit pretty easy to calculate.

Be aware that if you have more than one term of minimal order, you cannot apply the preceeding reasoning, because the sum of terms of order $n$ can have an order higher than $n$, e.g.
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x-x^2}{x^2+x^3}\neq\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^2}
$$
because $\sin(x)-x$ is of order $3$, despite both $\sin(x)$ and $x$ are of order $1$, so the correct elimination is
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x-x^2}{x^2+x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^2}{x^2}
$$

**Example**

Calculate the following limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+2\sin(x^2)+3\sin^3(x)+4\tan(x)+5\log^2(x+1)}{3\cos(x)-3+\arcsin(x)+\log(1-x^2)}=(**)
$$
We can observe that
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1\neq0 \\
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin(x^2)}{x^2}=2\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=2\cdot1=2\neq0 \\
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{5\log^2(1+x)}{x^2}=5\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}
    {x}\right)^2=5\cdot1^2=5\neq0 \\
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{3\cos(x)-3}{x^2}=-3\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=-3\cdot\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}\neq0
\end{align}
so all these terms are of order $2$. Next, we have
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{3\sin^3(x)}{x^3}=3\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^3=3\cdot1^3=3\neq0 \\
\end{align}
so this term is of order $3$. Finally
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{4\tan(x)}{x}=4\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=4\cdot1=4\neq0 \\
& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}=1\neq0
\end{align}
so these two terms are of order 1, the lowest in the numerator and also the lowest in the denominator, so
$$
(**)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4\tan(x)}{\arcsin(x)}
$$

Comment: why did you remove 0 from R?

Comment: and can you explain this infinitesimal order stuff? I am not very familiar with non - standard analysis

Comment: $0$ should be removed because otherwise we have, e.g., that $x^3$ is of order $k=0,1,2,3,$ for $x\to0$, while we only want $3$. This is not standard analysis, it is called (I translate from Italian) _principle of substitution of infinitesimals_, and I can only find Italian references. But try to follow the reasoning, instead of trying to enclose this in a given frame.

Comment: one question, what do you mean when you say order? I am trying to understand, but some terms and ideas I don't get

Comment: I think I would be able to understand more if you showed example of method you meant

Comment: what is $ h_r $ and $ k_s$

Comment: The meaning of order is nothing more that what is said in the post: given the stated limit related to $f_i$, "We can informally say that $f_i$ is an infinitesimal of order $h_i$ in $a$". All try to add some examples.

Comment: I mean, what does it mean to have an infinitesimal of some order?

Comment: $f$ is an infinitesimal of order $n$ in $a$ if $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}=l\neq0$$

Comment: hm, I'm starting to get it I think but I think I need few example of your method

Comment: @DDD4C4U I added an example

Comment: I read this 10 times but I still can't understand the idea, can you say it in a different way?

Comment: why are terms of order greater than one neglected?

Comment: It is like $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+x^3}{2x^2+3x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1+x)}{x^2(2+3x^2)}=(*)$$ and given that $1+x\to1$ and $2+3x^2\to2$, we have $$(*)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\cdot1}{x^2\cdot2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{2x^2}$$

Comment: I think I understand it after thinking a lot, it is like you factor out least power monomial from numerator and denominator, and then take limit

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example, we have
$$
\frac{\sin(x) + \sum_{j=2}^n x^j}{x} = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x^j,
$$
where the last term tends to zero for $x\to0$.

Comment: This was not exactly my question..

Comment: @DDD4C4U If I understand you correctly, you can factor out a term in the denominator and then divide the numerator by this term as in this example. Then, apply the additivity of limits.

Comment: I didn't mean to give impression that I only wanted to reomve stuff from numerator, I want to remove from denominator as well

Comment: @DDD4C4U But the factored-out term (here: $x$) is removed from the denominator. Or should it be also removed from  $\frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: I am looking for generality , I only gave the example so that people could understand what I am saying

Comment: @DDD4C4U But you can generalize from this example. It is the same technique.

Comment: this additive property you've stated doesn't apply for stuff in denominators

Comment: @DDD4C4U Sure, but you can divide by the denominator. In this case, since the $\sin$-function is analytic, we can express it by a Taylor series and divide much further.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider $$\frac{\sum \limits_jf_j(x)}{\sum \limits_j q_j(x)}$$ then $L=\frac{\sum \limits_jf_j'(a)}{\sum \limits_j q_j'(a)}$. So we  can remove $f_k,\,q_m$ if $f_k'(a)=0$ and $q_m'(a)=0$