Switching a function inside a limit with another ‘similar’ function
Question
Given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(f(x),x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(g(x),x)$ both exist, can we say that: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(f(x),x)\stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(g(x),x)$$
This is equivalent to replacing a particular occurrence of $f(x)$ in a given limit with $g(x)$
What are the conditions under which the above equality holds true?

Context
I was trying to solve this limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan^5(x)+x^3}{\arctan^7(x)+x^3}$$
Simplifying the given question to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^5+x^3}{\arctan^7(x)+x^3}$ and then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^5+x^3}{x^7+x^3}$, we do get the correct answer. However both of the steps depend on the fact described in the Question above.
For example (and to clarify), in the first step:
$$h(y,x)= \frac{y^5+x^3}{\arctan^7(x)+x^3}$$ $$f(x)=\tan(x)$$ $$g(x)=x$$

Hint: You can always replace $f(x)$ with $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)$ and by using $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, the result goes.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(f(x),x)= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}h(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x),x)\stackrel{!}{=} \lim_{x\rightarrow a}h((\lim_{x’\to a}\frac{f(x’)}{g(x’)})g(x),x)$$ The last equality is not true always. @BoweiTang

To put it more clearly, you cannot always compute an inner limit without solving the entire limit.

Would the downvoter care to comment, so that I could improve my question?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767931/removing-superfluous-functions-from-limits

Even if we assume $f,g,h$ are all continuous, this does not necessarily hold. Consider
$$f(x)=x,g(x)=x+1,h(x,y)=x-y, a=+\infty$$
If we assume $h$ is uniformly continuous, this will be true. We can even weaken the condition to that at least one of $f,g$ is continuous. Here is the proof.
WLOG, assume $f$ is continuous. We claim that for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}\cap \overline{g((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}\neq \varnothing$
If this does not hold, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}\cap \overline{g((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}=\varnothing$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}$ must be a closed interval, so $\sup \overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}<\inf \overline{g((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}$ or $\inf \overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}>\sup\overline{g((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}$
WLOG, we consider the first case. Note that this means there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\sup \overline{f((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}+\delta<\inf \overline{g((a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon))}$, which is contradicted to $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.
With this claim, we can prove the original proposition. Assume $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}h(f(x),x)\neq \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}h(g(x),x)$. Then we can find $\varepsilon,\delta>0$ s.t. for any $x_1,x_2\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, we have $|h(f(x),x)-h(g(x),x)|\geq \varepsilon$.
Since $h$ is continuous, we can find $\delta'>0$ (we can assume $\delta'<\delta$) s.t. as long as $|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2|<\delta'$, we have $|h(x_1,y_1)-h(x_2,y_2)|\leq \varepsilon$.
Then, consider the interval $I=(a-\frac{\delta'}{3},a+\frac{\delta'}{3})$. According to our claim, we can find $x_1,x_2\in I\subset(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ s.t. $|f(x_1)-g(x_2)|<\delta'$. Moreover, note that $|x_1-x_2|<\frac{2}{3}\delta'$. Thus we have $|h(f(x_1),x_1)-h(g(x_2),x_2)|<\varepsilon$, which is a contradiction!
P.S.1.We can similiarly prove the case where $a=\infty$.

If we assume $a$ is finite and the range of $f$ near $a$ is bounded, we can show that the proposition is still true without uniform continuity of $h$, since we can restrict $h$ on a bounded region.


Thanks for providing the answer. Unfortunately, I am not experienced enough in this topic to understand your answer fully. I do understand the counterexample you’ve provided though. Would it be possible to create a counterexample if we add a condition stating that $a$ must be finite?

Though I shouldn’t be talking about something I have no idea about, but still: does $f((a,b))$ with a bar over it mean ${f(x)\mid a<x<b}$? Or the closure of that set?

It means its closure.

If you don't require $h(x,y)$ is continuous at $y=a$, this will be trivial by a change of variable. For example, $a=0$, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|},g(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}+1,h(x,y)=x-\frac{1}{|y|}$. However, if you still require $h$ is continuous on the whole plane, things will be more subtle.

Thanks again! I will try to look up the terms used in your answer and see if I can understand them.
